# Rails ordering relationship output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails application in which pages has many comments.  So the relationships in the models are:

**page.rb:** `has_many :comments`

**comment.rb:** `belongs_to :page`

Now I display the comments in my view by doing:

```
<% @page.comments.each_with_index do |comment| %>
   <%= comment.comment %>
<%end%>
```

I want to know how I can paginate this with will_paginate.  I also want to make it so that the newest one (one with greatest id shows up first).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To order the comments:

```
has_many :comments, :order => "id DESC"
```

To use will_paginate just push the logic into your controller:

```
@comments = @page.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the pagination but you can query with an order like this:

```
@page.comments.find(:all, :order => "id desc")
```

Maybe will_paginate will take care of the rest?

EDIT: As per John's comment (thanks!) the Rails 3 way is indeed:

```
@page.comments.order("id desc")
```

Comment: Looks like John's answer is a tad more comprehensive :)   anyways I'll leave my answer. My answer will order only for that specific query, instead of defaulting to ordering like that.

Comment: This answer is good too. Depends of if you want comments ordered by id as default or not.

Comment: Actually the rails 3 way to do this is @page.comments.order("id desc")

Comment: That would have been a good a bit ago, I may revert it in a bit, but I think I am done with it for tonight

Answer (score 0):

You could use scopes to provide this feature.  Scopes are essentially a way of filtering and/or ordering ActiveRecord models when asking for collections.

Scopes are a little different between Rails 2.x and 3.x.  In Rails 2.x you can use named_scope and default_scope.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => "id DESC"
end
```

Not surprising, **default_scope** defines a default scope used when fetching your records, as in a Comment.find_by_page_id(100).  Will paginate should fetch your records using the default scope you've defined.

In Rails 3.x you define a default scope like:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order("id DESC")
end
```

Hope this helps.